# How can I tell mysql the timezone throught connection string?

Tags: mysql, timezone

For some reason I am getting this error while trying to start my java app.

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'AEDT' is
>   unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure
>   either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration
>   property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize
>   time zone support.

I would like to be able to change the timezone on the connection string. So far I tried this:

> javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
>   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/returnit?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC"

and this:

> javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
>   value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/returnit?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Australia/Sydney"

But for some reason mysql is not picking up the timezone and still complains about AEDT?

Mysql connector version is 6.0.6
System I am running in MacOS
Mysql version is

**QUESTION:** Any idea about how to setup serverTimezone through connection string?

thank you very much

Comment: There is a similar question asked here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: @sudip yes I want to set the timezone throught the connection string. A potential solution from your link but didn't work

Comment: You want to set the serverTimezone property in mysql server instead of passing timezone as part of connectionString, right? Is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/19069310/452213 not working for you?

Comment: @sudip I want to tell mysql the timezone in the connection string. I preffer not to do that in the database configuration

Comment: `AEDT` is not a time zone id.  I'm guessing you want to pass `Australia/Sydney` instead.  See [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks, I tried this and unfortunately it didn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is an example of a connection string specifying serverTimezone:

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/returnit?useSSL=false&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"
```

Comment: Instead of "returnit" is the name of our project ? It's not working for me and my url is "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PhoneCompany"

Comment: Remove "amp" and ';' characters and change the name to your database's name: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOUR_DB?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC