# Logstash set another offset (00:00) for fields of DateTimeOffset type

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

Our `Logstash` moves data from `SQL Server DB` to `Elastic`. But it **changes offset of DatetimeOffset values** *(with 04:30 offset)* and sets another offset *(00:00)*. I know finally, values are the same, But why does it change my offset? And how can I prevent this?
What changes should I make to the Logstash configuration?

Answer (score 1):

If a column in your database is a date or time then there is [code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-integration-jdbc/blob/6a75566cad54805ff05a50a8a4879aede54a7967/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb#L258) in the jdbc input that converts it to a LogStash::Timestamp. Those are always in UTC.

If that results in the wrong timestamp, you may be able to use the [default_timezone](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-jdbc_default_timezone) option. Alternatively, you could use the serverTimezone option in the SQL connection string as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48916808/how-can-i-tell-mysql-the-timezone-throught-connection-string).

If you want the input to not do the conversion then CAST it to a non-date/time type in your SELECT.